# When do you use $ΔU= mCΔT$ in thermodynamics?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, temperature, dimensional-analysis, gas

I am confused between when to use $ΔU= nCvΔT$ and $ΔU= mCΔT$.
For example a question says

> 100g of water is heated from 30°C to 50°C, ignoring the slight expansion of water the change in its internal energy is? (specific heat of water= 4184 J/kg/K)

Which one should I use here, $nCvdT$ or $mCdT$?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the equation $\Delta U = m C \Delta T$, $m$ represents the mass of the matter, $C$ represents the specific heat (at constant volume) which is the **heat capacity per unit mass**, and $\Delta T$ represents the change in temperature. The total heat capacity is given by $m C$.

The equation $\Delta U = nvC \Delta T$ is exactly the same as the previous one, just expressed in a different way. You did not define any of the variables in your question, but I am going to guess that $n$ is the mass density and $v$ is the total volume of the matter - and therefore the total mass of the matter is $m = nv$.

In the problem you're trying to solve, you are directly given the total mass of the matter at hand, $m = 100\,\textrm{g}$. You are also given the change of temperature $\Delta T = 20^{\circ}\,\textrm{C}$. You need to therefore look up the specific heat of water at constant volume, and use the equation $\Delta U = m C \Delta T$.

Comment: I'm guessing that by $C_v$ they mean the specific heat at constant volume, not the specific heat times the volume. They are probably just confused about when it's valid, since for an Ideal Gas it is indeed true that $\Delta U=nC_v\Delta T$.

Comment: @FranDahab Could be. If $C_v$ represented specific heat at constant volume, then the equation $\Delta U = n C_v \Delta T$ would represent the change in internal energy per unit volume, and thus the $\Delta U$ of this equation would be different than the $\Delta u$ of the other equation. I assumed that $\Delta U$ simply meant change in total internal energy for the entire system (1 phase of matter). Ultimately all of this confusion could be solved if the OP wrote definitions for each variable.

Comment: Got it mate... Thanks